# Create an Input Area Box in an Excel Userform and Use each line as an entry in an array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, userform

I have trouble finding examples for this specific question.
I'm automating a task in Excel and I need users to paste a list of id-numbers in an areabox. When they click ok, I need my macro to get this list in an array so I can loop trough these id's and work with them (I want to check the formats, then paste the correct once in a column in Excel)

I tried and added a RefEdit on a userform, (multiline true, scrollbars both)
I've added this to be launched when click ok:

```
Dim data As Variant
Dim elemnt As Variant
data = Split(Simcards.simcardsArea.Text, vbNewLine)
For Each element In data
    MsgBox element
Next element
```

Is there a better tool for this usage? Or is this the way to go?
I need the user to be able to paste the list of id's from a copy of any program, Excel, notepad, e-mail,..

Thank you

Comment: Excel usually strips Chr(13) from a vbCRLF leaving only Chr(10) but I've seen it miss a few occasionally. Probably best to replace all vbcrlf with vblf then split on the vblf or you might end up with rogue Chr(13) chars after splitting something delimited with vbcrlf on a vblf..

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim arrayRange As Range
    Set arrayRange = Application.InputBox("Enter a range", "Range:", Type:=8)

    Dim myArr As Variant
    Dim size As Long: size = arrayRange.Rows.Count - 1 
    ReDim myArr(size)

    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim myRow As Long: myRow = 0

    For myRow = 0 To size
        myArr(myRow) = arrayRange.Cells(myRow + 1, 1)
    Next

    Dim myVal As Variant
    For Each myVal In myArr
        Debug.Print myVal
    Next myVal

End Sub
```

The trick is to pay attention how the array is assigned. The idea is that the array should be as big as the size number of the rows in the selected area, hence:

```
Dim size As Long: size = arrayRange.Rows.Count - 1
ReDim myArr(size)
```

The `-1` is needed, because the arrays start from `0`, unless someone writes `Option Base 1` on the top of our code and break anything we have hoped for.
As arrays start with a `0`, it is good to loop this way:

```
For myRow = 0 To size
    myArr(myRow) = arrayRange.Cells(myRow + 1, 1)
Next
```